# Count MySQL rows in PHP for current month

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to display the number of orders of current month and I don't know the query to do it:

This is the code:

```
$stats_orders_curr = mysql_query(
                     'SELECT count(1) FROM orders 
                      WHERE MONTH = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
                      AND YEAR = YEAR(CURDATE())'
);

$orders_curr =  mysql_fetch_array($stats_orders_curr);
$orderscurr = $orders_curr[0];
```

Comment: as far as I know it is count(*)

Comment: @geryjuhasz - `COUNT(1)` and `COUNT(*)` should return the same result.

Comment: didn`t ever try that :)

Comment: Are there fields in the table called MONTH and YEAR, or something that records the order date?

Comment: place echo mysql_error(); to see the error message. Maybe it will give a no database selected error.

Answer (score 2):

I would change the SQL from

```
SELECT count(1) FROM orders WHERE MONTH = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

To

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `orders` WHERE MONTH(`orderdate`) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(`orderdate`) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Where `orderdate` is the field that records the date of the order ;)

Comment: Yes, a little bit works, but it shows me only **0** Orders. The date field is format like that _1371359836_ . Thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `orderdate` >=  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01 00:00:00')
```

It's good practice to avoid functions on fields something like

```
where MONTH(orderdate)
```

because you will loose using of indexes.